# Xenforo + Cloudflare Flexible SSL

Tags: ssl, https, cloudflare, xenforo

Today I installed my side for Xenforo and Cloudflare Flexible SSL. The Xenforo admin panel is working, and have SSL Green lock. But, if I opened for forum (index.php example), the browser (Chrome, Opera, Mozilla, etc.), blocked for load scripts. If I accept for load, the forum load. But no have green lock, only admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like Xenforo is having trouble working out what protocol you're using (as Cloudflare is proxying traffic to your origin over HTTP whilst it's going to end user over HTTPS).

The best option in this case is to install the [Mod_Cloudflare Apache extension](https://www.cloudflare.com/technical-resources/#mod_cloudflare) as it will automatically correct Apache headers so the SSL environment variable is correct.

If not, you can set the following in your .htaccess file, so that Apache sets the HTTPS environment variable to on when it sees X-Forwarded-Proto:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=On
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Working.

Comment: @MeilHelt which method you tried? I pasted SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=On this line on the top of  .htaccess file but didn't work.. Admin control panel is showing https but not website